# Merge [Hebrew], and [Language]?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Pretty self-explanatory. Is the fact that [hebrew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew) is more specific than [language](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) enough of a reason to keep them apart?

Comment: @elikakohen There's [tag:Aramaic], but there's no [tag:Chaldean]. As you can see below, the question was also asked of [tag:English].

Comment: ... Sorry, I meant that there may also be questions regarding Aramaic, or Chaldean - that would be distinct from "Language".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both English and Hebrew have sufficiently many questions on Mi Yodeya about them in their own right that it makes sense to maintain tags for each of these.

Comment: Fair enough for [tag:English], but most of the [tag:Hebrew] questions, even the ones left open, seem to do more with Hebrew Language than Hebrew as it pertains to Yiddishkeit.

Comment: @DonielF If there are open questions that you think ought to be closed, there's a process for that. I submit that even if you closed all of the [tag:hebrew] questions that the scope-strictest around here would object to, you'll still have very many questions rightfully tagged [tag:hebrew]. This is not at all surprising, given the many ways in which the Hebrew language is important to Judaism.

Comment: Fair enough. (Note I can't vote to close other people's questions, but that's an aside.) So...do we just let this question die out now?

Comment: @DonielF It's up to the community to vote on this question and its answers. If you consider this answer dispositive, you can signal as much by marking it "accepted."

Comment: @DonielF You will soon enough! In the mean time don't forget to flag for closure, as that sends the question to the eyes of other high rep users who can vote on it.